# How to pass an yml object to powershell in a DevOps pipeline?

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to pass an object from our DevOps Pipeline to a powershell script, however I'm struggling as I am not getting it to work, see output. The convertToJson function seems to add line breaks and also seems not to format the json properly (second amount value is suddenly without quotes). Is there a different way I can pass the object to my Powershell script?

pipeline.yml:

```
parameters:
- name : objectTest
  type : object
  default: 
  - fruit: apple
    amount: 1 
  - fruit: pear
    amount: 1

# Omitted some stuff for readability

- task: AzurePowerShell@5
      name: testObject
      inputs:
        pwsh: true
        ScriptPath: test.ps1
        scriptArguments:
          -object '${{ convertToJson(parameters.objectTest) }}'
```

test.ps1:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    [string]$object
)
Write-Host $object
```

Output:

```
##[error]Invalid script arguments '-object '[
  {
    "fruit": "apple",
    "amount": "1"
  },
  {
    "fruit": "pear",
    "amount": 1
  }
]''. Line breaks are not allowed.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use this workaround

```yaml
- task: AzurePowerShell@5
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'full-subscription'
    ScriptType: 'InlineScript'
    Inline: |
      $test = '${{ convertToJson(parameters.objectTest) }}'
      ./test.ps1 -object $test
    pwsh: true
```

Comment: Gives a similar error.

Comment: Could you check my update?

Comment: Ah was just thinking in the same direction, can you delete the "script:  |" line? And it also works without the "$test = [string]::join("",($test.Split("`n")))" line. :)